# SpeechSynthesisUtterance onboundary event not firing properly

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

We i am using SpeechSynthesisUtterance onboundary event not firing properly. Its stoping middle of the sentence sometime.

Anyone come across this case? Pleas help.

```js
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
     utterance.lang = 'en-UK';
     utterance.rate = 1;
utterance.onboundary = function(event){
      console.log(event);
   };
```

Comment: What does "*Its stoping middle of the sentence sometime*" mean? It fires only *x-n* times while you have *x* words in your utterance's sentence?

Comment: It's not firing x times if we have x words in sentence sometimes. I am using it in post method results.

Comment: And can you find what is common to all these *sometimes*? Do you have an example that will reproduce it **every** time?

Comment: I am working on angular1.6, with in the application i am able to reproduce every time. But outside of the application its firing every time.

Comment: 1. There is no en-UK, only en-GB, will this make a difference?. 2. Maybe add angularjs tag to your question for more views?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an issue with garbage collection (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509488#c11)
If you store the utterances in a variable with global context it works:

```
window.utterances = [];
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( 'hello' );
utterances.push( utterance );
speechSynthesis.speak( utterance );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug specifically with:

- Chrome
- Using the Extra Set of Chrome Voices (i.e., if you use *Google UK Female*, for instance, as opposed to the infamous *Microsoft Dave*).

Source: [Bugs.Chromium.org - Issue 521666: speechutterance onboundary event doesn't fire](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521666).

As stated by one of the developers...

> Native speech synthesis on Mac OS X, Windows, and Chrome OS all support boundary events at the word level.

That is to say, if you are using the Chrome speech synthesis (non-native), you will get irregular behavior on these alternate languages.